What is the ReferenceError: providers_2 is not defined?
I try to write a UT for a service in Angular.
The Service will look like this
@Injectable()
export class TimeZoneStateService {
  constructor(
    @Optional()
    @Inject(GLOBAL_CONFIG)
    private config?: ViewConfig,
  ) {}
}

and the UT
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import {
  GLOBAL_CONFIG,
  TimeZoneStateService,
} from '@sdo/givs-common-service';

describe('TimeZoneStateService', () => {
  let service: TimeZoneStateService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        TimeZoneStateService,
        {
          provide: GLOBAL_CONFIG,
          useValue: {
            timeZoneResolver: () => 'America/Toronto',
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    service = TestBed.createComponent(TimeZoneStateService).componentInstance;
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
)

the error message when I run the UT is
enter image description here
I try to pass the UT, and don't know why the have such error

You need to use TestBed.inject to get the service. The method you are using is only for components.
Before:
 service = TestBed.createComponent(TimeZoneStateService).componentInstance;

After:
 service = TestBed.inject(TimeZoneStateService);


Please try the below code:
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { GLOBAL_CONFIG, TimeZoneStateService } from '@sdo/givs-common-service';

describe('TimeZoneStateService', () => {
  let service: TimeZoneStateService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        TimeZoneStateService,
        {
          provide: GLOBAL_CONFIG,
          useValue: {
            timeZoneResolver: () => 'America/Toronto',
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(TimeZoneStateService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

